# Join to dataframe on X.n = Y.n + 1

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a data frame  **X** with data like:

```
n    val
------------
1    4
2    3
3    0
```

and another, **Y**, with the same columns, like:

```
n    val
------------
1    288
2    12
3    130
4    1230
```

How can I create an additional column in X, that is the value of the following (`n` + 1) `val`?

Expected output is:

```
n    val  val2
------------
1    4    12
2    3    130
3    0    1230
```

Apologies as I'm sure this has been asked before, I'm just having trouble finding it, and can't figure it out using `join` or `merge`, those seem to only take column names as inputs.

Comment: So you are looking for [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `merge`

```
df=df1.merge(df2.assign(n=df2.n-1),on='n')
   n  val_x  val_y
0  1    4.0     12
1  2    3.0    130
2  3    0.0   1230
```